# preg_match colon separated "key value" string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have a string like this:

```
brand:bmw model:e90 otherkey:this is a value otherkey2:another's value
```

can anyone suggest the right regex? I can't find the right one.
What i expect is something like:

```
array(
[0] => array(brand,bmw)
[1] => array(model,e90)
  .......
)
```

and my try:

```
/^([a-z]+):(.*?)(?=(^[a-z]+:|\z))/i
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: what is your expected result and what you have tried?

Comment: Add what you have tried, a minimal code example (and warning, errors etc you encountered). This way people do not have to solve the problem for you, but can help you with your specific problem.

Comment: @Ste Have fun with this [regex](http://regex101.com/r/qD9cH5) `(?P<key>[^:\s]+):(?P<value>.*?)\s*(?=[^:\s]+:|$)`

Comment: If you have any choice in how you store this, I would suggest using serialize instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php - Even using a colon (blacklisting colons in the key and the value) would work soo much easier. I guess HamZa's regex works though.

Answer (score -1):

It's not that straight forward seeing as there is no real splitter between the values and the next key. Try avoid using space as a splitter unless you got something wrapping the value.

> key:"value" key:"value" key:"value" key:"value"